# Why isn't this string to binary conversion working?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, binary

I am storing IPv6 addresses as `BINARY(16)` and trying to search through them using the hexadecimal representation, eg: `FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000`.

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM ipv6 WHERE HEX(address) = 'FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000'
```

However, this does not:

```
SELECT * FROM ipv6 WHERE address = CONV('FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000', 16, 2)
```

No error messages, just doesn't return any results.  Is MySQL unable to handle the conversion using `CONV()`?

I could use the first option, but I imagine the second option is much faster in a large database as it isn't having to convert every address in the table.

**Update:**

`UNHEX()` seems to work great as pointed out by Jack.  Standard conversions (as of 5.6) using `CONV()` seems to max out at 8 bytes (64-bit) or in hex form `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` so it can't handle a full 128-bit ipv6 address.

After some deliberation, I believe Salman's answer is the best way to handle hexidecimals (using hexidecimal literals).  However, `unhex()`, afaik, is required if you are using parameter binding in PHP since quotes will be added and will prevent MySQL from evaluating it as a literal versus a char string.

Therefore you will have to choose the best solution for you.  Hexidecimal literals is a little bit faster but if you're handling user input, then unhex with parameter binding may be the best solution.

Comment: Please give an example of same values you're saving, and how you're inserting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hexadecimal literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html):

```
SELECT * FROM ipv6 WHERE address = 0xFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000;
SELECT * FROM ipv6 WHERE address = X'FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000';
```

If you are using PDO, you can simply do this:

```perl
# insert packed address
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ipv6(address) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute(array(inet_pton("2001:0DB8:85A3:0000:0000:8A2E:0370:7334")));

# select packed address    
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ipv6 WHERE address = ?");
$stmt->execute(array(inet_pton("2001:0DB8:85A3:0000:0000:8A2E:0370:7334")));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

# verify the result
echo inet_ntop($rows[0]["address"]);
# 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
```

Comment: This solution actually is a bit faster than using unhex.  The only problem is I can't seem to figure out how to use it with PDO prepared statements.  I tried `WHERE address = X?` but I get a syntax error.  I could validate the hex separately and use it directly in the query but I assume the manual validation would cancel out the small savings this achieves versus unhex.

Comment: I think `WHERE address = ?` should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The parameter binding adds quotes.  So it doesn't evaluate it as a hexidecimal literal, only a char string.

Comment: @devon if you are using PHP+PDO then what exactly does the `var_dump($ip_to_find)` look like? If `$ip_to_find` is a binary string (16 gibberish characters) then you can pass it as-is. PDO will escape unsafe characters, be it `0x0000...` or `'\0\0...'`. If `$ip_to_find` is a hexadecimal-encoded representation of a binary value (32 hexadecimal characters) then you need to pass `hex2bin($ip_to_find)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to convert each item to hexadecimal, you can do the opposite:

```
SELECT *
FROM ipv6
WHERE address = UNHEX('FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000');
```

This will do binary string comparisons as you would expect.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks, didn't even realize UNHEX existed, but that definitely makes sense.  It looks like CONV can't handle any conversion of this size.

Comment: @Devon `CONV()` is a mathematical function whereas what you need is a string function.

Comment: CONV does work up for smaller numbers though, it looks like it maxes out at 64-bit integer, or in hex form `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

Comment: @Devon Yeah, integers aren't 128bit yet ;-)